# Emacs silently changes font when using another text encoding

Tags: emacs, cyrillic, face

I have installed emacs25 (Kubuntu 18.04.1). I have text/tex files in Cyrillic in different encodings: utf-8 and cp1251.

The font face for utf-8 cyryllic seems OK, just the one I set with `customize-face default`, but when I open a file in cp1251 encoding, the font face isget changed to some ugly-looking cyrillic face.

I don't understand why this happens. How can I make it keep the same font for all cyrillic text encodings?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got a solution.

First, see which encoding (and whch font) is used for particular cyrillic letters. Place a mark onto a letter and press `M-x describe-char` . Important info is in the lines 'preferred charset' and 'xft'. I see windows-1251 and some lenty fontname.

Next, add a line to ~/.emacs to setup fontset in apropriate way:
`(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'windows-1251 "Hack")` (in my case, I used the Hack family as a sans serif mono font).